# Swift: Swipe background image set

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Looking to make the fullscreen background image change when swiping left/right within a single page app controller (without using the page view controller). Can you show me an example or point me to one? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It has both Objective-C and Swift versions. You can just download the source code to see how it really works:
[iOS Tutorial: Using UIPageViewController to create a content slider](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift).

Comment: I was kinda looking for a way to do it without the page view controller. Do you happen to know how to get rid of the navigation on the page view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for on Github.

https://github.com/babumirdha/SwipeGestureWithImageView